# One Moment In Time (the title of the song) : no time for less (what's for less?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5RIfTn5WU0 (at 2mins:22seconds)

I want it all. No time for less.

Q: No time for less = I don't have time to lose?

Comment: No time for less than 'all'. She doesn't want a part, she wants it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No time for less

means

> There is no time for less [than I want].

and she wants it all.

Comment: What could be the part of speech of "less" here?